# OOP hierarchy in Python

Tags: python, oop

In Python, everythig is a object.

If we create an instance of a user defined class, below how the instance is created.

Step:1 The `__call__()` method present in type class, is invoked.

Step:2 The `__call__` method in turn, calls the `__new__()` and `__init__()` methods respectively to create the instance of the user defined class.

```
class Foo()
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

`Foo()`  <--- here, the above two steps happen.

Similarly when an object is created for the Foo class, the `__call__()` method needs to be called and it in turn
will invoke the `__new__()` and `__init__()` methods.

Could someone please help where this `__call__()` method is located.
I am trying to understand how object **for** (not of) the class is constructed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It belongs to the class `type`:

```py
>>> type.__call__
<slot wrapper '__call__' of 'type' objects>
```

Since classes are instances of `type`, they have this method:

```py
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> A.__call__
<method-wrapper '__call__' of type object at 0x55d97f5cbf60>
```

So creating an object like `A()` is equivalent to invoking `A.__call__`, which in turn is equivalent to invoking `type.__call__` with `A` as the `self` parameter:

```py
>>> A()
<__main__.A object at 0x7efe29a5fac0>
>>> A.__call__()
<__main__.A object at 0x7efe29a5f460>
>>> type.__call__(A)
<__main__.A object at 0x7efe29a5eef0>
```

Comment: Thanks Kaya3 for your response.  Is it the same __call__() method inside the type class, used to create object of the class (say Foo) and object for the class (say Foo()) ?

Comment: @user3103957 A statement like `class A: pass` which creates a class is executed by invoking the builtin function `__build_class__`, so it is `__build_class__.__call__` which gets invoked. The actual class object is probably then created by some C code rather than by invoking the `type` constructor in Python, but this will be a CPython implementation detail; conceptually, it's OK to say that `__build_class__` creates a class object by invoking the `type` constructor (or equivalently, `type.__call__`) with three arguments - the class name, its base classes, and a dict of members.

Comment: Thanks Kaya3. Now its clear that the class object (i.e: class A: pass) will be created by using __call__() available in type class. Then is my understanding that "normal object (like: A()) creation involves the same type.__call__()" not correct ? Is A() instance created by a different __call__() method ?  Thanks!

Comment: They're the same `__call__` method, yes. You can create the class like `type('A', (), {})` to invoke the `type` constructor, or equivalently like `type.__call__(type, 'A', (), {})`.

Comment: Ah, ok. To iron out, we can state these: 

__call__() has overloaded versions of methods. when passed with 3 arguments, it creates an object for a class. And when passed with 4 arguments, it creates an object of the class. 
(continued in in below comment...)

Comment: In the former invocation, the __init__() &__new__() invoked from __call__() are from inheritance chain of the given class (i.e: the class, its parent class & up to object class).
In the later (when invoked with 4 arguments), the __init__() &__new__() invoked from __call__() are from meta class (type). If we override those methods in another meta class (extending type), then they will be invoked.

hope, I am correct on the above. could you please confirm. Thanks!

Comment: `type.__call__` isn't overloaded; it takes a class plus some other arguments, and invokes `__new__` on the given class with those given arguments. `type.__new__` creates an instance of `type` (i.e. a class) and `A.__new__` creates an instance of `A`. As it happens, `type.__new__` *is* overloaded, but that is not related to any of these examples.

Comment: I am completely baffled now. As you correctly mentioned, both of the below statements produce a class object A.  why do we need to supply type object for statement-2? If I remove 'type' argument in statement02, it is erroring out.

    `k1 = type('A', (), {})` and 
    `k2 = type.__call__(type, 'A', (), {})`

Comment: @user3103957 Because when you invoke an object as a function, it looks up the `__call__` method on the class and automatically binds the object as the first argument to that method, so e.g. `obj.method(1, 2)` is equivalent to `Class.method(obj, 1, 2)`. In this case, `type` is both the object and the class, because `type` being a class means it is an instance of `type`.

Comment: Hi Kaya3, my sincere apologies for coming late. I ran few lines of code to make my understanding clear. I am very much obliged to your help. My sincere appreciation for taking your time and answering my questions. Thanks again!!

Comment: I create a custom type class by inheriting the type class.
While I create the SampleClass, it works fine. But create an instance of SampleClass, I get the error TypeError: type.__new__(SampleClass): SampleClass is not a subtype of type. 

Is it possible to advise why I get this error? Thanks!
(code snippet is in the next comment...)

Comment: `class CustomMetaClass(type):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Custom call method is invoked while creating instance of {str(self)}.")
        ins = super().__new__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        ins.__init__(ins)
        return ins


SampleClass = CustomMetaClass.__call__(CustomMetaClass,"SampleClass",(),{})
SampleClass()`