# __call__() method in meta-class in python

Tags: python, call, metaclass

I am having the following piece of code.

```
class CustomMetaClass(type):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Custom call method is invoked from custom meta class.")

class Sample(metaclass=CustomMetaClass):
    def method(self):
        print("Printing from a method")
```

I have a custom meta-class and a normal class (Sample). 'Sample' is associated with my custom meta-class.

Since every thing is an object in Python, whenever the interpretter comes across a class definition, an instance of 'type' is created for the user defined class.
This is done via by calling the `__call__()` of the meta class.

In the above case, Sample class is associated with my custom metaclass and hence the print statement should have been executed; But it not run actually.

But when I create instance of Sample ( `Sample()` ), the print method invoked. As for as I know (from a different stackoverflow question), the same `__call__()`
method in the meta class is used to create instance for the user class (while defining the class) as well of the user defined class (i.e: `Sample()` )

Can someone please help where I am wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you're not mixing it up with `__new__`?

Comment: yes, just for understanding/self demo, I dont mix this with __new__() or __init__().. thanks

Comment: Shouldn't your class `CustomMetaClass` `__call__` method return an instance?
I don't get an error when I redefine it to:

```
class CustomMetaClass(type):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Custom call method is invoked from custom meta class.")
        return instance
```

Comment: "from a different stackoverflow question" Which one? you should link your research

Comment: yes, it does not make sense if we don't return an instance. but I have the lone print statement to confirm my understanding. Irregardless of whether we return an instance or not, the print statement must have executed.

Comment: Here is the SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75967784/oop-hierarchy-in-python/75967818?noredirect=1#comment133995690_75967818

Comment: I think you might be looking for `__prepare__`

Answer (score 3):

> But when I create instance of Sample ( Sample() ), the print method
> invoked. As for as I know (from a different stackoverflow question),
> the same **call**() method in the meta class is used to create
> instance for the user class (while defining the class) as well of the
> user defined class (i.e: Sample() )

This is a complex subject, and it turns out you got it wrong.
The `__call__` in a class metaclass is what is called when you will create *ordinary* instances of your classes defined with that metaclass.  (In this case, when you execute `Sample()`) .

What is executed in the metaclass when the class itself is created (the `class Sample(...):` statement and its body) are the methods `__new__` and `__init__`.

Perceive that it is *exactly* the same thing that takes place for ordinary objects: when you instantiate a class, with , say `Sample()`, the `__call__` method on the class of "Sample" (which is the metaclass) is called, and its effect is to call the `__new__` followed by the `__init__` method in the class itself - (the ones defined in the body of `class Sample(...):`.

So, what takes place is that when executing a "class" statement - when its body is processed, the `__call__` of the *metaclass* of the *metaclass*  is called - ordinarily that is `type.__call__` in what is likely is the weirdest part of all: `type` is its own metaclass. This is hardcoded in cPython's source. And the execution of this `type.__call__` will call the metaclass' `__init__` and `__new__`. The `__call__` on the "first stage" metaclass is executed only when creating class instances.

```
In [7]: class Meta1(type):
   ...:     def __call__(mcls, *args):  # called when a class is created
   ...:         print("at __call__ of Meta1")
   ...:         return super().__call__(*args)
   ...: 

In [8]: class Meta2(type, metaclass=Meta1):
   ...:     def __new__(mcls, *args):
   ...:         print("at __new__ on Meta2")
   ...:         return super().__new__(mcls, *args)
   ...:     def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):  # called when an instance is created
   ...:         print ("at __call__ on Meta2")
   ...:         return super().__call__(*args, **kw)
   ...: 

In [9]: class Sample(metaclass=Meta2):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         print("at __init__ on Sample")
   ...: 
at __call__ of Meta1
at __new__ on Meta2

In [10]: s = Sample()
at __call__ on Meta2
at __init__ on Sample
```

Comment: How does `__prepare__` compare? Does the meta-meta-class’s `__call__` call it?

Comment: No - prepare is called by another mechanism directly coded in a function availiable as a builtin named `__build_class__`. To customize the call to prepare and class body execution, the stdlib contains the types module, particular `types.prepare_class`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html